# Uploading a file that is created in a form (Not pulled from any kind of file storage) to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku, amazon-s3

I am creating a personal website that will allow me to create and save files to my Amazon S3 Bucket.

The setup is this: I have a form with a text input for a file name and a textarea for the body of the file.

The idea: Be able to save the file as the file name AND extension (ie: if the file name is 'index.html' it will save it as an html object in my bucket). It will save what ever is entered into the textarea as the body content of the file.

Errors: 
1) POST **heroku-url** 500 (Internal Server Error)
2) *Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGVUABEAAAAAxuQAAQABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABHREVGAAABgAAAAC4AAAA0ArgC7UdQT1MAAAGwAAAQ6AAALgxKsqRTR1NVQgAAEpgAAAH3AAAELqI5y+RPUy8yAAAUkAAAAE8AAABgaGyBu2NtYXAAABTgAAABlAAAAkQkRATXY3Z0IAAAFnQAAABeAAAAugDsQf1mcGdtAAAW1AAABZcAAAvNb3/BHGdhc3AAABxsAAAACAAAAAgAAAAQZ2x5ZgAAHHQAAEApAAB3CtbiupxoZWFkAABcoAAAADYAAAA2BkubWWhoZWEAAFzYAAAAIAAAACQHFARfaG10eAAAXPgAAAI6AAAEEk4TN4Nsb2NhAABfNAAAAhIAAAISiLhpam1heHAAAGFIAAAAIAAAACACigzgbmFtZQAAYWgAAACUAAABHhQGLdJwb3N0AABh/AAAAq4AAASRk5y6n3ByZ...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*

Note: I am using Heroku and I used 'heroku config:set' command to store my AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and stored my bucket name (S3_BUCKET).

code:

```html
<h1>New File</h1>

<hr>

<form method="POST" action="/save-as">
  <input type="text" id="file_input" name="file_input" placeholder="File Name"><br>

  <textarea id="file_body" name="file_body"></textarea>

  <hr>
  <h2>Save changes</h2>

  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();
app.set('views', './views');
app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.listen(port);
console.log("App is listening on port: " + port);

aws.config.region = 'us-east-2';

const S3_BUCKET = process.env.S3_BUCKET;

app.get('/', (req,res) => res.render('index.html'));

app.post('/save-as', (req, res) => {
    const s3 = new aws.S3();
    const fileName = req.query['file_name'];
    const fileBody = req.query['file_body'];
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET, 
        Key: fileName,
        Body: fileBody
    }
    s3.putObject(s3Params, (err,data) => {
       if(err) throw err;
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
        res.write("Successful!!");
        res.end();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely off the topic of resolving the error but you can write it as console.log(`App is listening on port: ${port}`) those are backticks not quotes for an object literal so you don't need to use concatenating.